# Batch import of textfile causes memory issue with Doctrine and Symfony (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, batch-file, doctrine-orm

I'm importing a textfile of 15MB into a mysql-database. When I'm doing the following, the data are not imported but the memory usage is still constant about 28MB.

```php
$handle = fopen("textfile.txt","r");
while (($data = fgetscsv($handle, 1024, "|")) !== false) {
    // processing data
}
fclose($handle);
```

When I bring now Doctrine into play, the memory usage still grows up and up until memory is overflow and the script crashes.

```
gc_enable(); // Enable Garbage Collector
$handle = fopen("textfile.txt","r");
$i=0;
while (($data = fgetscsv($handle, 1024, "|")) !== false) {
    $myEntity = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->find($data[0]);
    if (!$myEntity) {
        $myEntity = new MyEntity();
        $myEntity->setId($data[0]);
        $myEntity->setName($data[1]);
    } else {
        $myEntity->setName($data[1]);
    }
    $this->em->persist($myEntity);
    if ($i%100==0) {
       $this->em->flush();
       $this->em->clear();
       gc_collect_cycles();
    }
    $i++;
}
fclose($handle);
$this->em->flush();
gc_disable(); // Disable Garbage Collector
```

The memory usage grows up to 256 MB and then the script causes memory issue because of the limit which is set to 256 MB. So what (else) can I do to keep the memory usage low?

Comment: I suspect you are running a symfony command. Are you using `--env=prod` ?

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't help. Same memory issues. Trying now the other solution mentioned below.

Comment: I have to +1 @touki 's suggestion! Call your URL with app.php and not app_dev.php when using Symfony. This saved my day (now can import 40k entries without a problem). Looks like the Symfony Profiler was the bad guy.

Answer (score 1):

Try delaying every Doctrine's call as much as you can. In this particular code, `Doctrine`'s `find()` gets called for each file row. You could optimize this.

```
$dataChunk = array();
while (($data = fgetscsv($handle, 1024, "|")) !== false) {

    # collect the data into array
    $dataChunk[$data[0]] = array( $data[0], $data[1] );

    if ($i > 0 && $i%100==0) {
        # lets prepare and persist the data
        $idsToRead = array_keys($dataChunk);

        # read all entitties with given IDs
        $entities = $this->doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')->findEntitiesById($idsToRead);
        $existentIds = array_map($entities, function($e){ return $e->getId(); });

        # find out which Ids are non-existent
        $newIds = array_diff($idsToRead, $existentIds);

        # Overwrite the name for existent entity
        foreach ($entities as $e){
            $e->setName($dataChunk[$e->getId()][1]);
        }

        # Create new entities for non-existent IDs
        foreach ($newIds as $id){
            $e = new MyEntity();
            $e->setId($id);
            $e->setName($dataChunk[$id][1]);
            $this->em->persist($e);
        }

        # finally, flush the data
        $dataChunk = array();
        $this->em->flush();
        $this->em->clear();
        gc_collect_cycles();            
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Some things to pay attention to:

- `findEntitiesById` would be custom repository method. It does not exist out-of-box
- database communication get executed on every 100th record
- be sure to skip 0th row (i = 0, i % 100 == 0 => `TRUE`). I have added the condition
- be sure to apply the same logic if you do not reach modulus 100 at the end (number of rows is not dividable by 100)

Comment: That code looks good, but it doesn't give a positiv effect on memory consumtion. I'm still getting: "PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted". There is also a little error, the parameters of array_map are in the wrong order.

Any other ideas what else I can do?